# Fatal error: touch: cannot touch '/tmp/nosalt': Permission denied

Tags: deployment, salt-stack

I am seeing this error while deploying `inbox-renderer`, the past solutions have been to delete the `/tmp/nosalt`, but i don't have permission to do it, could anyone help with this? thanks

```
Fatal error: touch: cannot touch '/tmp/nosalt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the deploy command telling you that it can't highstate the host because the host has a file at the location `/tmp/nosalt`.

This file can be there because a users put it there to prevent `highstate` from running or because it never got cleaned up after a deploy.

If this role is stateless, I would leverage [boxman](https://robinhood.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BO/pages/615252394/Boxman%3A+Enabling+teams+to+manage+their+own+cloud+resources?search_id=aa9ec3eb-20e5-44e9-9ada-85208139bc16) to terminate the host. Then start the deploy again.